# Select (dplyr) operator with '-'

Tags: r, dplyr

How to use SELECT (dplyr library) operator with name containing '-'? For example:

```
AdultUCI %>% select(capital-gain)
```

caused:

[image: error]

Comment: How did you get that name in your data.frame? That's not a valid column name. This will likely cause errors in many cases (as you've already seen). Usually in invalid characters (such as `-` in this case) are replaced by `.` to make valid column names.

Comment: I download it from https://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/datasets/Census+Income

Comment: Well, I'm more interested in how you imported it into R than where you downloaded the data. I'm assuming you must have just done `names(df)<-x` to assign the names which bypasses the default checks. Try `names(df)<-make.names(x)` instead.

Comment: @MrFlick Maybe `fread` from `data.table`? Try `fread("a-b, c\n 1,2",header=TRUE)`

Comment: @MrFlick I just load these data (names come from repository)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try this

```
data.frame(`a-b` = 1, c = 2, check.names = FALSE) %>% 
  select(`a-b`)
#   a-b
# 1   1
```

Answer (score 2):

We can use `matches` inside `select`

```
data.frame(`a-b` = 1, c = 2, check.names = FALSE) %>% 
         select(matches('-'))
#    a-b
# 1   1
```